# Error with PDF in JqueryUI Datatables Buttons extension Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui, pdf

I'm having an issue with the Buttons extension for JQueryUI Datatables. The PDF button does not work when generating a large PDF in Chrome, but it works just fine for a smaller PDF. The large PDF is also generated just fine in both Safari, and Firefox. Is there a memory limit on Chrome, or anther known issue that would be causing this behavior? The table is 600ish lines long, 12 pages, as an approximation of size. This doesn't seem ludicrously large to me.

Thank you.